# Restrict Shipping method only at the checkout

Tags: checkout, onepage-checkout, shipping-methods

I want to use the only one shipping method at the checkout, but it don't distrub the internal shipping methods and the other shipping methods working besides checkout.

Actually I am doing something with the shipping methods at the customer account, I also don't want to disturb that. I only want to use only one shipping method at checkout.

I tried many plugins and also observer but it didn't work. Please any one can help me regarding this and provide me the working solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try below Extension:

https://landofcoder.com/magento-2-shipping-restriction.html

*Hope it's fulfill your requirements*

Comment: Can this extension also hide the shipping method only at the checkout and not distributed the other shipping functionality on the front end as I am using the shipping related functionality on the customer account '

Comment: I'm not sure but it's not affecting your customer account customisation. Once you check and let me know if you have any issue

Comment: okay sure I will check

Comment: It's not doing what I want